# For what purposes have YOU used T4?

Tags: visual-studio, code-generation, t4

[T4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) has existed for several years in Visual Studio, but doesn't get a lot of attention.  However, for those that know it, there seems to be some very creative and useful purposes.

I am researching some different ways that T4 is used, and I would appreciate to hear how YOU may have used it for real life scenarios.  I am primarily interested in non-standard and creative uses.

Some interesting examples:

1. Phil Haack uses T4 [to create static CSS files from .less](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/12/02/t4-template-for-less-css.aspx)
2. To [Generate WPF and Silverlight Dependency Properties using T4 Templates](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/DependencyPropertyCodeGen.aspx)

**Note**: I realize this is a discussion-oriented question, but the answers could be helpful to others.  I have tagged it as subjective and also marked as "community wiki", so please allow the question to remain open.  Thanks!

Comment: Haha, Phil Haack's website is showing Yellow Screen of [ASP.NET] Death.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used the T4 Templates within the [sharp-architecture](http://sharparchitecture.github.io/) to generate everything from models to controllers to basic views.

Definitely worth checking out, even if you just want to see some advanced examples of T4 templates in action

Comment: broken link, now redirects to scammy ads, answer no longer useful

Answer (score 8):

I am not a big fan of the stringy-ness of app.config/web.config, so I use T4 to read those files and make an AppSettings/WebSettings class that wraps the connection strings and key/values in a real class.  This means that, as long as I always use AppSettings.SomeValue to reference my app.config, I get compile time checking, which is *really* nice.

Comment: nice, do you have that T4 template available somewhere?

Answer (score 4):

I use T4  to:

1. Generate CRUD SQL Server and Oracle scripts.
2. Generate Data Access Layer, based on a database schema
3. Layer Generate Business Logic Layer, based on a database schema
4. Generate ASP.Net webforms, both HTML and codebehind, based on a database schema (scafolding).

It gives me a good, quick, simple, basic starting point for my projects.

And the best is I'm in control.

[Here you can download an example of my templates](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B7gHrdOYQf9yNDUxM2E1MWYtNjhkNy00NDQ4LWI2NjEtOTYwYWU5YTczYmYw)

Answer (score 2):

[SubSonic 3.0](http://subsonicproject.com/) makes heavy use of T4 templates for generating your entity code.

Essentially it calls `GetSchema()` on your database connection and runs each table it finds through the T4 entity template.  The great thing about using T4 here is that if you don't like the way it's handling your database schema, just edit the template.

I've tweaked the T4's to handle MySQL databases better for my situation, as I make use of many `tinyint` columns which the default T4 maps to `byte` types.  A quick edit to the T4 gave me the type I wanted instead for my application entities.

Comment: And if you're really good you can make it support a database it wasn't intended to. I got a partial port of SubSonic to PostgreSQL by editing only the template files.

Answer (score 2):

**LINQ to SQL templates for T4**
http://l2st4.codeplex.com/

Templates replicating the functionality of the SQLMetal and the LINQ to SQL classes designer code-generators for both C# and VB.Net requiring just Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: I'm considering switching my code to use these templates. Anybody have any testimonial resources or some encouraging words about using l2st4?

Answer (score 2):

Check out this podcast on T4 by Scott Hanselman talking with Kathleen Dollard.
http://www.hanselminutes.com/default.aspx?showID=170

Answer (score 2):

I've used T4 to generate:

- proxies (design time, for injecting/wrapping monitoring
  code/logging/... in a very specific exposed api).
- interface generation for a one-on-one interface/class mapping
- replace reflection
  code by "directly/real" calling code (maintenance advantage of
  reflection code, but performance of the actual code) for instance
  when allowing access to properties through an indexer, or something
  in that direction.
- xml generation for a java project (couldn't find a
  T4-like solution for java, that is easily shared within a company, T4
  is easy because it's build in and you can run it from command line)
- generate enums from a master database (we generated them both for a delphi-code base and .Net code base)

Answer (score 1):

T4 Templates are used heavily in the Web Service Software Factory ([Service Factory](http://servicefactory.codeplex.com/)).

Answer (score 1):

See here for a list of more than 30 T4 Generators from the community in several areas including ASP.NET,WCF, UML, ADO.NET, .NET

http://t4-editor.tangible-engineering.com/How-Do-I-With-T4-Editor-Text-Templates.htm